# What are jointly regular-epimorphic families?

Tags: category-theory

In nLab they talk about finite jointly regular-epimorphic families: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coherent+coverage.
I know what jointly epimorphic families are: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/jointly+epimorphic+family. And what regular-epimorphic families are: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+epimorphism. But what are jointly regular-epimorphic families precisely? And a good follow up question is, what is a jointly regular-epimorphic family when the category is coherent?